# Sometimes diff isn't shown in edits to code inside source fences

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, diff

It seems the visual highlight of revision/code differences in source fences is currently broken for some posts in the suggested edits review queue.

- **Example 1.** [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29271567). The 3rd line of code was edited but there's no visual highlight.

  [image]
- **Example 2.** [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29267087). The code line was changed but there's no highlight, notably the source fence is one single line.

  [image]
- **Example 3.1.** [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29272877). There seem to be two inconsistencies, the difference highlight is shown when reviewing the item in the review queue.

  [image]
- **Example 3.2.** but [if you review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64923181) the edit by clicking the `edit` link directly on the post the diff highlight is not shown.

  [image]

I think the highlight difference is essential for reviewers, I was left starring at the source fences trying to find the differences in code when reviewing these items.

Comment: Cross site duplicate (MSO): [The revision history does not show the latest content correctly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly)

Comment: @Makyen hadn't seen it because it didn't have [tag:suggested-edits] tag. However, the 2 bug reports are complementary, this one adds examples of the suggested review queue and also the diff between the queue and directly reviewing on the post.

Comment: I have created [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/9154) that should fix the issue and the "hotfix".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hotfix from [my answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408993/3023052) has been expanded to cover the `/review/suggested-edits/{id}` page. Highlight.js was overriding the styles used for showing additions and deletions. My hotfix turns off Highlight.js on these revision pages so that additions and deletions are shown correctly.

Notably, the hotfix has a regression of turning off syntax highlighting on this page. See [my Meta SO answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408993/3023052) for more details.

Comment: Since you're looking into it [maybe this is related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400727)?!

Comment: @bad_coder The change that broke this was introduced in the past couple of weeks, unfortunately this isn't related so no easy win there  That bug is approaching the top of our bug backlog though, so stay tuned 