# How can I properly embed a code block into a Markdown table cell? Alternatively, how can I insert newlines into a code block without using `Enter`?

Tags: support, markdown, code-block, tables, newline

I have the following fenced code block:

````
```<br>a = 1<br>b = 2<br>```
````

I would like to replace the `<br>`s with some other character `?`, so that it acts like a newline, so that the resulting string

````
```?a = 1?b = 2?```
````

displays as though I had typed

````
```
a = 1
b = 1
```
````

That is, so that it displays like this:

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

---

The reason for wanting to do this is:

I'm using [TablesGenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create Markdown tables. Whenever I input a fenced code block into a cell, TablesGenerator.com takes my newlines and turns them into spaces (or into `<br>` if I've checked the `Line breaks as <br>` option). So a Markdown table that I've formatted to have the content:

````
```
a = 1
b = 2
```
````

In the 2nd row, 2nd column, TablesGenerator.com converts into:

````
| Inline Code   | Code Block                    |
|-------------  |------------------------------ |
| `a = 1`       | ```<br>a = 1<br>b = 2<br>```  |
````

That is, TablesGenerator.com turns my newlines into `<br>`s, which leads to the Markdown table displaying undesirably as:

| Inline Code | Code Block |
| --- | --- |
| `a = 1` | `<br>a = 1<br>b = 2<br>` |

---

The only workarounds I've found are not great. They are:

- Instead of a code block with new lines, add a row for each line:

| Inline Code | Code Block |
| --- | --- |
| `a = 1` | `a = 1` |
|  | `b = 2` |

- Instead of using a Markdown table, use a text table:

```
+-------------+------------+
| Inline Code | Code Block |
+-------------+------------+
| a = 1       | a = 1      |
|             | b = 2      |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: i use ``` concatenated with the lenguaje example ```php and a new line to start my code...

Comment: When my questions or answers include or need data from a database: I usually use 2 tools: the html table that makes it easy to copy to excel and create a csv that can be imported ... or an external repository if it is very large like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac62c97/3

Comment: in sites like SO and esSO we need more emulation for languages ... mainly database ... since users usually ask for a minimum reproducible example ... but it is a bit difficult or complex if the site does not have a tool to do as the database case.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Thanks! Can you link to a question or answer where you do this? That would help.

Comment: yes but it is in Spanish; will you have a problem with that?

Comment: Yes! Si! Spanish is fine (I speak Spanish and even if I didn't, it's the structure of the table I'm interested in). And are you able to have a code block as the content of a table cell? Thanks again!

Comment: check this: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/491912/46896

Comment: in this case I use some capture and the external repository; in conjunction with code blocks.

Comment: Thanks again! I may be mistaken, but I don't see any markdown tables in that Q/A though. I see screen captures of database tables (e.g. .png's) and I see code blocks, but I don't see a code block within a markdown table.

Comment: join this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132048/walter-nunez

Comment: @Arcanis - The Omnipotent: Re *"we need more emulation for languages ... mainly database*": Such proposals are usually [not well received by the meta crowd](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413437/are-you-tired-of-running-into-deprecated-code-in-the-highest-voted-answers-on-st/413438#413438).

Comment: There are six [evil TABs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=8m49s) (trailing TABs for some of the table elements) in the Markdown table source after "TablesGenerator.com converts into". Could that cause trouble? There are [ways to remove them](https://pmortensen.eu/world/Text.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a: Markdown table, with column spanning, and syntax highlighting, in code blocks:

```python
| Inline code | Code block                 |
|-------------|----------------------------|
| <pre><code>`a = 1`</code></pre>   | <pre><code>a = 1</code><br><code>b = 2</code></pre> |
```

| Inline code | Code block |
| --- | --- |
| ```python a = 1 ``` | ```python a = 1 b = 2 ``` |

Comment: Thanks! Why are both `<pre>` and `<code>` needed?

Comment: @joseville, Imgur isn't allowing me to upload a screenshot to include in this comment otherwise I'd show you that if you remove all the "`<pre>`" it won't work. --- You can copy the example into a new answer and remove them, proving that it breaks.

Comment: interesting, which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox Android.

Answer (score 5):

The answer comes from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59369423/13881506.

### Adding line breaks to a code block

Use the HTML `<pre><code>` tags to format a code block, which can then include `<br>` tags to add line breaks:

`<pre><code>a = 1<br>b = 2<br></code></pre>`

displays as

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

which looks identical to a fenced code block (i.e. one using ```` ``` ```` and newline's):

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

### Code Block within a Markdown Table

The following Markdown table:

```
| Inline Code   | Block Code                    |
|-------------  |-----------------------------  |
| `a = 1`       | <pre><code>a = 1<br>b = 2</code></pre>    |
```

displays exactly as desired:

| Inline Code | Block Code |
| --- | --- |
| `a = 1` | ``` a = 1 b = 2 ``` |

---

#### Specifying a `lang` attribute in `<pre>` strips the `<pre>` HTML tag...

Stack Exchange [supports a strict subset of HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/271271). If you try to use HTML attributes which are not supported, then the HTML tag is completely stripped when Stack Exchange performs the Markdown to HTML conversion. So, adding a `lang` attribute to the `<pre>` tag results in it being stripped - the `<br>`s still produce line breaks, but the entire `<pre lang="python">` block stops displaying as a code block and displays as plain text instead, due to the `<code>`.

For example:

```
| Inline Code   | Not Block Code (inline code)              |
|-------------  |-----------------------------------------  |
| `a = 1`       | <pre lang="python"><code>a = 1<br>b = 2</code></pre>  |
```

undesirably displays as:

| Inline Code | Not Block Code (inline code) |
| --- | --- |
| `a = 1` | `a = 1 b = 2` |

#### Syntax highlighting will remove the `<br>` tags

If syntax highlighting is running on the code block, then the `<br>` tags are stripped when highlight.js runs in the reader's browser (see: [1 (MSO)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly), [2 (MSE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366899/sometimes-diff-isnt-shown-in-edits-to-code-inside-source-fences)).

For example:

```
<!-- language-all: python -->

| Inline Code   | The `<br>` is stripped by highlight.js.   |
|-------------  |-----------------------------------------  |
| `a = 1`       | <pre><code>a = 1<br>b = 2</code></pre>    |
```

displays without the `<br>` as:

| Inline Code | The `<br>` is stripped by highlight.js. |
| --- | --- |
| `a = 1` | ```python a = 1 b = 2 ``` |

Comment: What do you mean? The background gray of the inline code in the table does look a bit darker than the background gray of the block code in the table to me, but that's also the case outside the table.

Comment: @bobble you can show that ...

Comment: It seems to me that you should add this as a lack of support ... because it would be nice if it supported the *lang* attribute, although I don't know if you have any reference links that browsers support this; as far as I understand it is the country code in that place, instead of adding it as a response to the post.

Comment: How do I submit a feature request or bug?

Comment: in the same way that you just placed this post but at the end you put: **it is possible to support the lang attribute?** but you have to argue saying that browsers support it because I have not found it ...

Comment: I might in the future.

Comment: Using the lang attribute for that is misuse of that attribute. The attribute is meant to be one of the [IANA language subtags](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) per [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations) and represent the human language the content is written in, using it for anything else can screw with screen readers/HTML interpreters/validators etc. Highlight.js uses classes, if anything we should either use those, or a HTML5 data attribute (e.g. data-lang would be fine)

Comment: @ErikA can you provide a example of data-lang implementation???

Comment: @ErikA SE permits only a very limited subset of HTML. See: "[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/271271)" If you use *anything* other than what's specified there (e.g. including a `class` attribute), then the tag is stripped from the post in the Markdown to HTML conversion. You can use the HTML comment-like method of indicating a specific code syntax formatting language. However, highlight.js will strip any HTML formatting from within the code which it highlights, so if you want the `<br>` elements, then you can't have syntax highlighting.

Comment: I'm aware, it's just that if SE were to allow some way to specify programming language for `code` tags outside of the comment, it should not be the `lang` attribute, but either just a whitelist for what Highlight.js already uses (specific `class` attributes) or a data attribute imo.

Comment: Interestingly the "Code Block within a Markdown Table" method doesn't work for me while opted in to the new [editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor). The code breaks out of the table.

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the edit!